# How to check if std::vector is empty using RandomAccessIterator?

Tags: c++, iterator, std

I have written a function which takes a pair of RandomAccessIterators on a vector to sort it. This works fine. I wrote a Test case which exhibits strange behaviour.

A "simulation" of my function:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

int main(){

    std::vector<int> testing = std::vector<int>(0);

    assert(testing.begin() <= (testing.end()-1)); //why no fail?

    std::cout << (testing.begin() <= (testing.end())); //prints 1
    std::cout << (testing.begin() <= (testing.end()-1)); //prints 1 unexpectedly

    return 0;
}
```

When the vector `testing` is empty, I want the function to do nothing **OR** throw an exception. I do not know which one is better. Recommendations are appreciated.

I have read the C++ documentation on Iterators and know that `(testing.begin() <= testing.end())`  evaluates `True` when the testing is empty, as begin and end are the same for empty vectors.

Why is testing.end()-1 not evaluated smaller than testing.begin()? What can I do to get the desired behaviour, i.e. Exception or immediate return?

Comment: what do you expect `end()-1` to do when the vector is empty?

Comment: when the vector is empty then `begin == end`

Comment: A test for an empty vector (in fact all containers defined by the C++ standard library) would be `testing.begin() == testing.end()`.

Comment: you seem to expect that you can do arithmetics with iterators like you can do with integers, but thats not the case. When the vector is empty then `begin == end` and decrementing either of them makes no sense, it is undefined

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai I thought I would get an adress for both, then decrementing would get a different adress. My function does not know about testing, I do no want to pass it.

Comment: what do you pass to the function?

Comment: also in an array you cannot decrement a pointer to the first element. Also pointers are not simply numbers, where you can do arbitrary + and -

Comment: *why no fail?*  **Undefined behavior** is not required to "fail" in any manner.  It may crash.  It may appear to work.  It may "work" today, and crash tomorrow.  It may format your hard drive.  It may email your browser history to your grandmother.  It may cause time travel.  The compiler expects that the source code of the program does not contain undefined behavior.  Otherwise, all bets are off, nothing is guaranteed.

Comment: @Eljay good point, I did not find anything about what I want to do being undef. behaviour. Also see that I'm open to suggestions regarding my problem.

Comment: If the `testing` vector is empty, `testing.end()-1` is undefined behavior.  You may wonder/ask "Why doesn't the language detect this and define the behavior?"  Because that would impose a significant runtime performance penalty, and that would violate the #1 goal of C++:  performance.

Comment: @Tim *" I did not find anything about what I want to do being undef. behaviour."* -- See [LegacyBidirectionalIterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/BidirectionalIterator#Notes) on cppreference.com, specifically the "Notes" section: **"the behavior is undefined if `--container.begin()` is evaluated."** Technically, there are some other references to look at to see that this applies to vectors and that the semantics of `container.begin() - 1` matches `--container.begin()` (and you already know that `end()` equals `begin()` for this case), but those details do check out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I have read the C++ documentation on Iterators and know that `(testing.begin() <= testing.end())` evaluates `True` when the testing is empty, as begin and end are the same for empty vectors.

Indeed. `testing.begin() == testing.end()` when the vector is empty.

> Why is `testing.end()-1` not evaluated smaller than `testing.begin()`?

Because iterators are not integers. Decrementing an iterator makes it refer to the preceeding element in the container. There is no element before `begin`. When `end` equals `begin`, then there is also no element before `end`. You cannot decrement the `end` iterator in an empty container. `testing.end() -1` is undefined when `testing` is empty.

The `end` iterator is special, because it does not refer to an element in the container even when the container is not empty. Instead it *points to* one past the last element. Thats why for example in a container with 1 element you can decrement the `end` iterator once to make it equal to `begin`.

> What can I do to get the desired behaviour, i.e. Exception or immediate return?

If you want to check if the vector is empty you can either check if `testing.begin() == testing.end()` or use its `empty()` method. Undefined behavior does not raise an exception or causes an immediate return, it is undefined.

> I have written a function which takes a pair of RandomAccessIterators on a vector to sort it. This works fine. I wrote a Test case which exhibits strange behaviour.

You didnt show the function, but to sort a range of elements you need at least two iterators. One to the start and one to the end of the range. Inside your function you can compare those two iterators to see if the range is empty:

```
 template <typename Iterator>
 void foo(Iterator a, Iterator b) {
        // check for empty range
        if (a == b) return;
        // else do something
        // ...
 }
```

If a caller passes invalid iterators to that function then there is nothing the function can do about it, but its the calling code that needs to be fixed.

---

PS:

> Until now my function expects the begin() and the end()-1 as Iterators

C++ convention is to use half open ranges, `[a,b)`, where `a` is included but not `b`, and `[a,a)` denotes an empty range. It could be different, but thats how it is, it makes your loops look like:

```
 for( auto it = a; a != b; ++b) ...
```

For closed intervals, `[a,b]`, ie `a` and `b` both included in the range, it is not obvious how to represent the empty range (because `[a,a]` is the range containing 1 element). There are ways to deal with it and and C++ convention is not the only possible choice, but it is simpler to stick to it rather than to use a different one.

Comment: Until now my function expects the begin() and the end()-1 as Iterators, i.e. first and last element. Looking at your answer and comments above, best advice probably is changing the second argument to end() to check if they are not equal.

Comment: @Tim exactly. I didnt write it in the question, because I wasnt sure, but I already suspected that that is your misunderstanding. Convention is to use half open ranges, `[a ,b)` where `a` is included but not `b`, ie your loops are `for (auto it = a; it != b; ++it)`. I will add something to the answer

Comment: @Tim -- indeed; that's the approach taken throughout the standard library; a range is defined by an iterator that points at the first element and an iterator that points just past the last element. That lets you do things like `while (first != last) std::cout << *first++;` to write the contents of the entire range. That's much cleaner than doing the same thing when `last` points at the last element.